# select multiple columns from two tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to get data from two different tables t1 and t2.

The code below is returning this error: 
*'object' does not contain a definition for 'TotalAmt'*

```
        ViewBag.qry = from t1 in db.table1
                      from t2 in db.tabel2
                      where t1.uID == t2.uID && t2.PayStatus=="PENDING"
                      select new
                      {
                          t1.lastName,
                          t1.uID,
                          t2.PayStatus,
                          t2.TotalAmt
                      }.ToList();
```

view

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.qry)
                {    
                    @item.TotalAmt 
                }
```

Result

*'object' does not contain a definition for 'TotalAmt'*

Can anyone help? Thank you!

-Ceci

Comment: I think you are returning a linq query that didn't execute yet. Try to call .ToList() before assign the query to the ViewBag.

Comment: I updated the code but no joy.

Comment: You are returning a list of anonymous objects. Create a ViewModel class with those properties and modify the select new to Select new ViewModel. Then cast on the view your collection to a list of ViewModel, it should works.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Your passing a collection of anonymous objects (and `object` does not contain a property named `TotalAmt`. You need to pass a model - `select new MyViewModel { LastName = t1.lastName, .... }`